# CKEditor Prevent arrow navigation on keyup event

Tags: javascript, drupal, ckeditor

I'm writing own plugin for CKEditor in Drupal 7.

I'm trying to add mentions suggestions/autocomplete. When user press $ and then type some text appears popup with suggestions.

I'd like to enable navigation through suggestions with keyboard arrows. What should I do to "freeze" CKEditor when user press arrows?

This is part of my code

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('instrument_mentions', {
  init: function (editor) {
    var mentions = CKEDITOR_instrument_mentions.get_instance(editor);

    editor.on('contentDom', function(e){

      var editable = editor.editable();

       editable.attachListener(editable, 'keyup', function (evt) {

         if(/* suggestions are enabled and keyup is arrow*/) {
           // this is place where I'd like to disable 
           // arrows navigation so caret won't move 
           // and enable navigation on suggestions
         }

       });


    });
  }
});
```

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Actually what you should do is move the focus from the ckeditor to the new element (selectbox/dropdown) that you create. This way the `keyup/down` events will be on the selectbox/dropdown and not on the ckeditor.

Comment: Dekel, thanks ,but I don't want to disable input. I need something like this https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ but for CKEditor. I know how to get what user wrote after $, but when he press down/up arrow this event should be prevented and triggered on navigation in my suggestions block.

Comment: I never said anything about *disable input*. Double check my comment.